# Why is abstract private methods are not allowed in enums in java?

Tags: java, enums, encapsulation, information-hiding

Shouldn't it perfectly legal to write private abstract methods in enums? Is there a reason to forbid it that I cannot see?

A toy code example that does not compile is below; Lets assume I do not want to commit to any api other than the singleton being multiple or not.

Note that this can be implemented without abstract methods but this is just an example. I am asking if there is a general reason to forbid it.

```
 enum Count{
    SINGLE { 
        private int howMany() {
            return 1;
        }
    },
    DOUBLE{ 
        private int howMany() {
            return 2;
        }
    };  
    private abstract int howMany();// !! this declaration is illegal
    public boolean isMultiple(){
        return this.howMany() > 1;
    }
}

public static void main (String... args){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Count.values()));
    for(Count s : Count.values()){
        System.out.println(s.howMany() + " is " + (s.isMultiple() ? "many" : "one"));
    }
}
```

edit1: This is not asking why private abstract methods are forbidden in general. I am asking why use of it in enums is illegal providing an example that such use would make sense. This is not a duplicate. I couldn't find the answer in Stackoverflow. The answer to the general case does not apply here.

Comment: Keep in mind that your enum members are each an instance of its own _subtype_ of the enum type.

Comment: Then I cannot declare abstract methods in enums without sharing it to the package that the enum is in. Isn't this limiting information hiding?

Comment: There are many other limitations to the Java type system, there's nothing special about this one.

Comment: Ok, that is a good answer.

Comment: You can't declare abstract private methods anywhere, not just in enums. They can't be overridden, so they are pointless. What you're trying to do is accomplished by defining them as protected.